# How to make a field of objects

Tags: c#, objective-c, list, object, field

The field `Day[] calendar = new Day[365];` contains the class **Day**. As the teacher wanted.

But I don't know how to make my method **AddRecord** to save in this field. I use

```
hw.Add(new Homework(Convert.ToDateTime(part), parts[1], parts[2]));
```

to add it to **List**. But I need to save the data to the `Day[] calendar = new Day[365];` I just don't know how.

**Class Calendar**

```
class Calendar
{
    Day d = new Day();
    List<Homework> hw;
    Day[] calendar = new Day[365];
    //Day[0] = (Convert.ToDateTime("9.3.2008 16:05"), "M", "text"));

    public Calendar()
    {
        hw = d.GetList();
    }

    public void AddRecord(string line)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
        string part = parts[0] + " " + parts[1];
        hw.Add(new Homework(Convert.ToDateTime(part), parts[1], parts[2]));
    }
```

**class Day**

```
class Day
{
  List<Homework> hw = new List<Homework>();
  public List<Homework> GetList()
  {
     hw = new List<Homework>();
     string datum = "29.5.2005 16:55"; //!
     hw.Add(new Homework(Convert.ToDateTime(datum), "INF", "THREE"));// !
     return hw;
  }         
}
```

**class Homework**

```
class Homework
{
    public DateTime dt;  }         
    public string subject;
    public string content;

    public Homework(DateTime dt, string subject, string content)
    {      
        String.Format("{0:d.m.yyyy HH:mm}", dt);
        this.dt = dt;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
    }       
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for.  You should back up to the beginning and try to start again until you come across the very **first** thing that you don't know how to do.  _Then,_ you should do an internet search and see if you can find that thing out.  **If you can't**, then you can come back here, and ask about that 1 specific thing.

Comment: We would help if we could. We can't because your question is not clear, you haven't shown your classes and we don't know what to fix.

Comment: If I have to make Day [] Calendar field, how i will do it, if class Day contains List<Homework> hw = new List<Homework>();? We have a homework. We have to make a calendar with these conditions. But I really don't know how to connect these things..

Comment: here's the link to my project, I just need to use Day [] calendar at Calendar class and AddRecord method should somehow save to it, but I really don't know how http://www.sourcepod.com/joeifg10-52115

Comment: my code is too lenght to post here, I don't know, what should I post from the code. That's why i uploaded it to the website :)

Comment: @PetrKubelka: if the _relevant code_ is too long to be posted here, your problem is off topic anyway. You can ask specific questions with a specific issue here, not a requirement. Please read: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html

Comment: If you don't know what's applicable, then you aren't ready to ask a question here yet. But given that this is a architectural question, some class definitions would seem to be in order. If you have a friend, have him read the question and see if *he* understands it without looking at the linked code. When he does, it will be more likely that *we* can understand it. (**Note** if your friend is a good writer, he could probably give you even *better* advice).

Comment: Ok :D Let's try it again.

Comment: I have a field `Day[] calendar = new Day[365];`  I need to have this in my class Day `List<Homework> hw = new List<Homework>();` how to connect List and this field?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't have anybody to ask, that's why I am here

Comment: the filed `Day[] calendar = new Day[365];` contains the class Day. As the teacher wanted. But I don't know how to make my method AddRecord to save in this field `public void AddRecord(string line)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
            string part = parts[0] + " " + parts[1];
            hw.Add(new Homework(Convert.ToDateTime(part), parts[1], parts[2]));
        }`

Comment: It's in Class Calendar. It's working like this. But I need to Add a **string line** to the `Day[] calendar = new Day[365];`. Not to the **list hw** :)

Comment: And now it all makes sense. I'll answer if the question is reopened. Basically, you want to add the new record to the `Day`'s homework list; correct? Hint: Use `FirstOrDefault` to find the `Day` object you need, then add a method to `Day` to add the homework object to its list. BTW, please make all your future questions like the current state of this one. It still needs *some* help, but at least we can work with it.

Comment: I want to add record to `Day[] calendar = new Day[365];`. Thank you very much, I will try it tomorrow, I need to sleep now. I'll let you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish; you want to add the `Homework`record to its corresponding `Day` that is held by the `Calendar` object.

So first, we need to get the day:

```
DateTime dataDate = Convert.ToDateTime(part); //Or something
Day dueDate = calendar.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date = dataDate);
```

Note that this probably won't work first time, as you need to compare *just the day*. If you created the `Day` object with a different time than the `Homework` item had, the forthcoming `null` check will fail. I'll leave that comparison as an exercise to you, but feel free to leave a comment if you can't figure it out.

Then we need to give it the homework item:

```
if (dueDate != null) //Check if we found the date!
   dueDate.AddHomeworkItem(new Homework(dataDate, parts[2], parts[3]));
else
    throw new Exception("Date not found; invalid data read"); //Or something
                                            //Failing silently is usually bad
```

Of course, that requires a method in the `Day` class:

```
public void AddHomeworkItem(Homework item)
{
    hw.Add(item);
}
```

Thats it! A couple things I noticed while looking at your code:

1. You have a `Day` and `List<Homework>` in your `Calendar` class. You shouldn't need either of them. The `Day[]` is sufficient from what I can see.
2. It looked like you reused `parts[1]` in your add function. I doubt you want the date to be part of the subect! I fixed it in my code.
3. Your `Day` class pre-populates its `Homework` list with a nonsensical item. You probably need to remove that.

Comment: May I ask you, What the "days" stands for?

Comment: 1. one of the conditions is that I have to use `List<Homework> hw = new List<Homework>();` in `class Day` 2. parts[0] and parts [1] are separated string, 'cause I needed to separate each thing and save it to separated parts (Datetime dt, string content, string subject) 3. I agree, deleted the `hw = new List<Homework>();`

Comment: calendar, days, whatever. I still don't understand what should it do. Like where it comes from.

Comment: Where I can reach you? :D

Comment: @PetrKubelka Your edit to your post was pretty good! You don't get reputation for that though. Your edit to my post was inaccurate, so I had to reject it. You'll just get downvotes for your self-non-answer; so you should delete it. If you can edit a few other posts similar to what you just did to your own, you'll be up to 20 in no time!